# transactional replication-snapshot agent failure ... can anyone help me out

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

configured transactional replication ..source acting as publisher and distributor,target server acting as subscriber.. but I got error for snapshot agent at 93 % saying that in below screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you timed out.
Add this to your snapshot agent job step:

-QueryTimeOut 3600

The default is 1800 seconds which is 30 minutes.  Try giving it 1 hour or more.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146939.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151326.aspx

Comment: I will try adding that, Thanks